# mixing html code with php code

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am trying to use tcpdf library to generate pdf. I have a php file which contains variables like name,company name etc. But for displaying the products I am passing the array to  php. Now I want to display each element of array in a table row for that I have to write the php code but somehow I am having problem mixing PHP code with html code.Here is the part whihch contains the problem

```
    $html .= '<br><br>
              <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Invoice # {invoice_ref_id}</td>            
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Product</b></td>
                    <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
                    <td align="right"><b>Amount (Rs.)</b></td>
                </tr>'.
                foreach($item as products): .'   //This part contains error
                <tr>
                    <td>'echo products['item']'</td>
                    <td>'echo products['quantity']'</td>
                    <td align="right">75</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="right"><b>Total: 375</b></td>
                </tr>'
                endforeach;
             '</table>';

    $html .= '<br><br>Some more text can come here...';
```

Comment: just mix it, don't concatenate that way as it is in my opinion less readable (notice how even in this question you loose all code-coloration help ?), and of course you can't use PHP instructions (foreach) in the middle of a concatenation which is already an instruction on itself

Comment: If you have admin access to your server use http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ instead. Way more practical and easier to create on the fly PDFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of concatenating your HTML in a string that you will then need to echo, I would go to something like this :

```
<br><br>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Invoice # {invoice_ref_id}</td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Product</b></td>
        <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
        <td align="right"><b>Amount (Rs.)</b></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($item as products){ ?>  
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo products['item'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo products['quantity'] ?></td>
        <td align="right">75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="right"><b>Total: 375</b></td>
    </tr>
    <?php> } //ending the foreach ?>
</table>
<br><br>Some more text can come here...
```

Notice how even here HTML code is still correctly highlighted? It will probably be the same in your editor of choice. I find it much more readable, and you even avoid possible character escaping issues.

NOTE : I didn't fix your HTML, but there are several bad practices in it regarding semantics or even use of obsolete/deprecated tags. Here are a few:

- Don't use anything changing layout in your HTML, this is what CSS are for. For example, don't use `border` or `cellpadding` attributes on your table, use `table {border: 1px solid #ccc;}` (you can of course change color, that's an example) and `table td {padding: 5px;}` instead.
- Semantic best practices also imply not using `<br>` tag. Better define top or bottom margins to put some space between elements. (I must admit that's probably the only example where I value ease over semantic and sometimes use it myself though)
- `<b>` tag should be use only in very specific cases, [cfr this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b). In this specific case you can achieve the same effect (bold text) by using `font-weight: bold` on the desired cells, either by giving them a specific CSS class, either by targetting them with a CSS selector like for example : `tr td:nth-child(3) {font-weight: bold;}`}
- similarily, don't use `align` attribute, same thing, target the desired cell and use CSS property `text-align: right;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't continue the html with a concatenation straight after the foreach. You have to do `$html .=` again.

This

```
</tr>'.
foreach($item as products): .'   //This part contains error
<tr>
```

should be this

```
</tr>';
foreach($item as products): $html .= '   //This part contains error
<tr>
```

The same goes at the end of the foreach:

```
</tr>';
endforeach;
$html .= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong way. This should work -

```
$html .= '<br><br>
              <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Invoice # {invoice_ref_id}</td>            
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Product</b></td>
                    <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
                    <td align="right"><b>Amount (Rs.)</b></td>
                </tr>';
                foreach($item as products) {   //This part contains error
                $html .= '<tr>
                    <td>'. products['item']. '</td>
                    <td>'. products['quantity']. '</td>
                    <td align="right">75</td>
                    ........ ';
                }
$html .= '</table>';
$html .= '<br><br>Some more text can come here...';
```

Comment: what is the best practice though nowadays ? Concatenating all the HTML in one string to be echo-ed  afterwards or just mixing html and php opening/closing tags for php instructions ? i've always prefered the second approach as it keeps html code correctly highlighted and you don't have to escape any character, but is it bad to do it like that ?

Comment: Keeping `PHP` & `HTML` code separated is better practice.

Answer (score 0):

thie right way of doing something like this

```
 $html .= '<br><br>
          <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">Invoice # {invoice_ref_id}</td>            
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Product</b></td>
                <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
                <td align="right"><b>Amount (Rs.)</b></td>
            </tr>';
            foreach($item as products): 
             $html .='   //This part contains error
            <tr>
                <td>'echo products['item']'</td>
                <td>'echo products['quantity']'</td>
                <td align="right">75</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="right"><b>Total: 375</b></td>
            </tr>';

            endforeach;
       $html .=  '</table>';

$html .= '<br><br>Some more text can come here...';
```